# Parse web page content, not source code

Tags: java, android, json, spring, parsing

I'm working on an android project where I collect data from a web stream and use it within the app. Another member is working on the web side of the project which pushes the data I'm using to a webpage for me to collect.

The data is in JSON format and I've written a parser that parses the data as I need it. trouble is, when I connect to the URL that I'm want, I cannot get the JSON data from it.

The user interface of the web page displays the JSON that I need, but its not in the source code. When I grab the web page all I get is the source code without the data
here's the URL i'm connecting to:

http://ec2-54-194-27-150.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/eirwig-spring-mvc/tweeter-single

here's a sample display of what I need:

```
{ "id": "451355222041182208", 
  "text": "And @Andrewgobrien_ !", 
  "user": "darraghosulliv4", 
  "profileImageUrl": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/441638045100834816/8xZggJsT_normal.jpeg", 
  "con": "Ireland", 
  "lat": 51.86972925, 
  "lng": -8.42925046, 
  "countries": {"United Kingdom":2442,"Ireland":8401}, "tweetCount": 10843 }
```

and here's the source code of the URL:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Latest Tweet :</h1>

        <div id="Tweet"></div>

        <script>
        if (typeof (EventSource) !== "undefined") {
                var source = new EventSource( "/eirwig-spring-mvc/TwitterIreland");
                source.onmessage = function( event) {
                    document.getElementById("Tweet").innerHTML = event.data + "<br><br>";
                };
         } else { document .getElementById("Tweet").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
         }
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way I can collect the data from the user side of the page instead of the source code side?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to use the code to get the message stream:

```
 var source = new EventSource( "/eirwig-spring-mvc/TwitterIreland");
 source.onmessage = function( event) {
     ... do the processing here ...
 };
```

For querying the HTML you can try a headless browser such as [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html). This would allow to parse the page content after 2 secondsn when some tweet is already available:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://google.com', function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(page.content);
    }, 2000);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Can you explain the EventSource a bit more for me please?